# Python: create a file on S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, amazon-s3, upload

I have a function below for generating the rows of a huge text file.

```py
def generate_content(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        yield 'xxx'
```

Instead of saving the file to disk, then uploading it to S3, is there any way to save the data directly to S3?

One thing to mention is the data could be so huge that I don't have enough disk space or memory to hold it.

Comment: are you asking if you could upload some part of your transformation to S3 and at the end aggregate all those small files into a single big file? If you don't have enough memory, how are you going to read it?

Answer (score 0):

boto3 needs a file, a bytes array, or a file like object to upload an object to S3.  Of those, the only one that you can reasonably use that doesn't require the entire contents of the object in memory or on disk is the file like object, using a custom file object helper to satisfy the read requests.

Basically, you can call into your generator to satisfy the requests to `read()`, and boto3 will take care creating the object for you:

```
import boto3

def generate_content(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield 'xxx'

# Convert a generator that returns a series of strings into 
# a object that implements 'read()' in a method similar to how
# a file object operates.
class GenToBytes:
    def __init__(self, generator):
        self._generator = generator
        self._buffers = []
        self._bytes_avail = 0
        self._at_end = False

    # Emulate a file object's read    
    def read(self, to_read=1048576):
        # Call the generate to read enough data to satisfy the read request
        while not self._at_end and self._bytes_avail < to_read:
            try:
                row = next(self._generator).encode("utf-8")
                self._bytes_avail += len(row)
                self._buffers.append(row)
            except StopIteration:
                # We're all done reading
                self._at_end = True
        if len(self._buffers) > 1:
            # We have more than one pending buffer, concat them together
            self._buffers = [b''.join(self._buffers)]
        # Pull out the requested data, and store the rest
        ret, self._buffers = self._buffers[0][:to_read], [self._buffers[0][to_read:]]
        self._bytes_avail -= len(ret)
        return ret

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
generator = generate_content(100) #Generate 100 rows
s3.upload_fileobj(GenToBytes(generator), bucket, key)
```